# How to add multiple key values to a Protobuf?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

My `example.proto`

```
message Message {
    repeated string text = 1;
}
```

Library I am using: https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/

#### My Code:

```
var ProtoBuf = require("protobufjs");

var builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("example.proto"),
    Message = builder.build("Message");



 var myMessage = new Message({
     text: 'I like muffins and cupcakes1',
     text: 'I like muffins and cupcakes2',
 });


 var byteBuffer = myMessage.encode();

 console.log(byteBuffer);

 var decodedMsg = Message.decode(byteBuffer);

 console.log(decodedMsg);
```

#### Output:

```
{ buffer: <Buffer 0a 1c 49 20 6c 69 6b 65 20 6d 75 66 66 69 6e 73 20 61 6e 64 20
 63 75 70 63 61 6b 65 73 32 00 00>,
  offset: 0,
  markedOffset: -1,
  limit: 30,
  littleEndian: false,
  noAssert: false }
{ text: [ 'I like muffins and cupcakes2' ] }
```

Everything works fine, except the repeated string is not being repeated. It's only grabbing the last `test` key value. I'm trying to store multiple key's so I can add another key to this object later dynamically. Is this possible within Protobuf, or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMessage = new Message({
  text: 'I like muffins and cupcakes1',
  text: 'I like muffins and cupcakes2',
});
```

Here you've specified a Javascript object which has two fields called `text`. It turns out that, for some reason, this is not considered an error, but Javascript will happily throw away the first value and keep only the second. You can test this in your browser Javascript console:

```
> console.log({x: 2, x: 3})
Object {x: 3}
```

Yay Javascript.

I haven't personally used ProtoBuf.js but my guess is that it wants to represent repeated fields as lists. In that case, this should work:

```
var myMessage = new Message({
  text: [ 'I like muffins and cupcakes1',
          'I like muffins and cupcakes2' ]
});
```